# How to use animation as background image

Tags: background-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMCfS.jp)

Taking a look at that picure, animation is use as background in the left and on the right side of the page, an image is used as the background. Please hw can i go about using both backgrounds on one webpage.

Comment: 1) Your link is broken. 2) What is your programming language/framework? It's unclear from question

Comment: javascript jquery